# How to inject ngrx store into a library

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm creating a drag and drop angular module that I hope to externalize and publish to npm. The library will essentially allow the user to define drag and drop areas and associate ngrx actions with them.

```
const DND_RULES: DndRule[] = [
   new DndRule('area1', 'area2', MOVE_AREA1_TO_AREA2_ACTION.getAction),
   new DndRule('area2', 'area1', COPY_AREA2_TO_AREA2_ACTION.getAction),
]
```

A provided service will then dispatch the action that results from the rule.

My issue is that I need to integrate this library with the consumer's store. **Is there a way to provide the ngrx store via some static module method or link it to my store behind the scenes in some way?** `DndModule.provideStore(???)` I'm not sure what this would look like behind the scenes

Comment: why two questions with different context? [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230924/how-to-pass-data-into-and-an-angular2-module-and-through-to-a-module)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to pass data into and an Angular2 module and through to a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230924/how-to-pass-data-into-and-an-angular2-module-and-through-to-a-module)

Comment: one is asking how to inject ngrx, the other is asking how to inject raw data. if they can be answered simultaneously, then please offer your solution. otherwise I would expect the answers to differ.

Comment: when you are using a store and place it in a common module, the data can be shared across as well. what you want to inject into library!! elaborate your question

Comment: you're saying that external libraries can dispatch actions on behalf of my applications's store? That's my issue. I want to externalize the module.

Comment: which module? the store alone?

Comment: I want to externalize my drag and drop module. but it would need the privilege to dispatch actions on behalf of the consumer's store, so I will need to provide it. How can I do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145321/discussion-between-aravind-and-nate-may).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at how the router store is implemented, https://github.com/ngrx/router-store. 
The person trying to use your store will have to do some configuration and import the necessary actions, that they want to use.

`import { go, replace, search, show, back, forward } from '@ngrx/router-store';`